# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call

Tags: image, pytorch, classification, google-colaboratory

I tried DeIT classification using pytorch, it's a workable code. When I change my collab account to pro I still get an error in the second epochs:

I execute this instruction :

```
model_ft = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler) # now it is a lot faster
```

---

**Training model function:** :

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=10):
    since = time.time()
    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
        print("-"*10)
        
        for phase in ['train', 'val']: # We do training and validation phase per epoch
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train() # model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval() # model to evaluate
            
            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0.0
            
            for inputs, labels in tqdm(dataloaders[phase]):
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'): # no autograd makes validation go faster
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1) # used for accuracy
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                    
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
                
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step() # step at end of epoch
            
            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc =  running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]
            
            print("{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}".format(phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))
            
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict()) # keep the best validation accuracy model
        print()
    time_elapsed = time.time() - since # slight error
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print("Best Val Acc: {:.4f}".format(best_acc))
    
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
```

---

**After the first epoch i get this error**

```
Epoch 0/9
----------
100%|██████████| 175/175 [15:40<00:00,  5.37s/it]
train Loss: 6.2008 Acc: 0.0037
  1%|▏         | 3/232 [00:11<14:36,  3.83s/it]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c552e1f19194> in <module>
----> 1 model_ft = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler) # now it is a lot faster
      2 # I will come back after 10 epochs
2 frames
<ipython-input-22-58764f3d79c1> in train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs)
     26                     outputs = model(inputs)
     27                     _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1) # used for accuracy
---> 28                     loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     29 
     30                     if phase == 'train':
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/timm/loss/cross_entropy.py in forward(self, x, target)
     20     def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
     21         logprobs = F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)
---> 22         nll_loss = -logprobs.gather(dim=-1, index=target.unsqueeze(1))
     23         nll_loss = nll_loss.squeeze(1)
     24         smooth_loss = -logprobs.mean(dim=-1)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

( my outputs are matched, my dataset has 37374 images and 488 classes

```
 Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=192, out_features=150, bias=True)
  (1): ReLU()
  (2): Dropout(p=0.3, inplace=False)
  (3): Linear(in_features=150, out_features=488, bias=True)
)
```

I tried `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"` and still have the error)

Comment: it might be indexing issue such as `-1` on label